# how to use same function on multiple rows of same column html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**The Checkbox Function only working for the row1, when multiple rows added from database it shows the checkbox but checkbox function did not work for them**

```js
function selectOnlyThis(id) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i).checked = false;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.color = "blue";
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.color = "Red";
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.myCheckbox2 {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body data-spy="scroll">
  <!-- TOP MENU NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner" style="font-size:40px">
      <img class="" alt="" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:40px;width:50px;height:40px;" src="img/icon.png"> </img>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Welcome to Electronic Notice Board 
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand pull-left" href="#" style="color:Grey;padding-left:10px;"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <div class="" id="home">
    <!-- HOME -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <!-- PHONES IMAGE FOR DESKTOP MEDIA QUERY -->
      <div class="span3 visible-desktop">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="img/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>WELCOME</h3>
                <p>UIIT Department</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/slide3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
          </a>

          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:20px;">Student Information</button>
        </ul>

        <?php
     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","timetable");
     if($link) {
      //echo "coonected succesfuuly";
     }
     $query1 ="select * from notice";
     
     $run = mysqli_query($link,$query1); 
     
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
     ?>
            <ul>
              <li style="color:grey; font-size:25px;line-height:1.5; ">
                <?php echo $row['student_notice']; ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
          <?php } ?>

          <ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:20px;"> News & Events</button> 
          </ul>

          <marquee id="test" behavior="auto" direction="up" height="auto" scrollamount="2" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" style=" width:400px;height:320px;text-align:justify;">
            <?php
      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","timetable");
      if($link) {
       //echo "coonected succesfuuly";
      }
      $query1 ="select * from event";
      
      $run = mysqli_query($link,$query1); 
      
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
      ?>
              <p>
                <a href="#" style="color:grey; font-size:25px;line-height:2;"><img src="img/New.gif" style="width:20px; height:20px; font-size:18px; text-align:; ">
                  <?php echo $row['event']; ?>
                </a>
              </p>
            <?php } ?>
          </marquee>          
          <br><br>
          <table border="3px" align="center" width: "" style="font-size:15px;height:350px;width:400px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:22px">
                <B> Time: </B> </td>
              <td Style=" border:3px;text-align:center;font-size:20px"> 
                <select style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:20px;width:200px; height:60px;">
             <option > 8:00 AM to 9:20 AM </option>
             <option > 9:30 AM to 10:20 AM</option>
             <option> 10:30 AM to 11:20 AM</option>
             <option> 11:30 AM to 12:20 PM</option>
            </select> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:22px">
                <B> Total Class: </B> </td>
              <td Style=" border:3px;"> 
                <select style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:20px;width:200px; height:60px;">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option> 
                  <option>2</option> 
                  <option>3</option> 
                  <option>4</option>
             <option>5</option> 
                  <option>6 </option>
             <option>7</option>
             <option>8</option>
             <option>9</option>
             <option>10</option>
             <option>11</option>
             <option>12</option>
             <option>13</option>
             <option>14</option>
             <option>15</option>
             <option>16</option>
             <option>17</option>
             <option>18</option>
             <option>19</option>
             <option>20</option>
             <option>21</option>
             <option>22</option>
             <option>23</option>
             <option>24</option>
             <option>25</option>     
            </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:22px">
                <B> Class being Held: </B>
              </td>
              <td Style=" border:3px;">
                <select style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:20px;width:200px; height:60px;">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option> 
                  <option>2</option> 
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
             <option>5</option> 
                  <option>6 </option>
             <option>7</option>
             <option>8</option>
             <option>9</option>
             <option>10</option>
             <option>11</option>
             <option>12</option>
             <option>13</option>
             <option>14</option>
             <option>15</option>
             <option>16</option>
             <option>17</option>
             <option>18</option>
             <option>19</option>
             <option>20</option>
             <option>21</option>
             <option>22</option>
             <option>23</option>
             <option>24</option>
              <option>25</option>
                </select> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:22px">
                <B> Cancel Class: </B>
              </td>
              <td Style="border:3px;"> 
                <select style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:20px;width:200px; height:60px;">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>7</option>
              <option> 8</option>
              <option>9</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>11</option>
             </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <table border="3px" align="center" style="font-size:15px;height:350px;width:400px ">
            <tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;color:grey;background-color:lightblue;font-size:22px">
                  <B>Rescheduled Class:</B> </td>
              </tr>

              <?php
            //$day1=date("l");
            //    $shift1='morning';
            $day1=$_POST['selectday'];
            $shift1=$_POST['selectshift'];
            // echo date('e');
            //$date11=date('d-m-Y');            
            
            //$date11=$_POST['date'];
            //echo "$date11";
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","timetable");
            if($link) {
             //echo "coonected succesfuuly";
            }
            $query1 ="SELECT * from rescheduleclass where  shift='$shift1' && day='$day1'  ";
            
            $run = mysqli_query($link,$query1); 
    
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            ?>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:18px; width:450px;">
                    <B> <?php echo $row['reclass1']; ?> </B> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:18px; width:450px;">
                    <B> <?php echo $row['reclass2']; ?> </B> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:18px; width:450px;">
                    <B> <?php echo $row['reclass3']; ?> </B> </td>

                </tr>
                <?php
              }
             ?>
          </table>
      </div>
      <!-- APP DETAILS -->
      <div class="span3">
        <!-- ICON -->
        <div class="visible-desktop" id="icon">
          <?php
      //    $day1=date("l");
      //    $shift1='morning';
      
      $day1=$_POST['selectday'];
      $shift1=$_POST['selectshift'];
       ?>
          <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:20px; color:red;"> Time Table Spring-2017 Semester (Morning) &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="" style="position:center;font-size:20px;"><?php echo $day1; ?>  </button> </h1>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table width="1300" heigth="900" border="1">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" style="color:black;background-color:lightblue;">
                    <B> Class </B>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" style="color:black;background-color:lightblue;"> 8:30 AM to 9:20 AM</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="color:black;background-color:lightblue;"> 9:30 AM to 10:20 AM</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="color:black;background-color:lightblue;"> 10:30 AM to 11:20 AM</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="color:black;background-color:lightblue;"> 11:30 AM to 12:20 PM</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
            //$day1=date("l");
            //     $shift1='morning';
            $shift1=$_POST['selectshift'];
            $day1=$_POST['selectday'];
            //$shift1=$_POST['shift'];
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","timetable");
            if($link) {
             //echo "coonected succesfuuly";
            }
            $query1 ="select * from timetable_morning where shift='$shift1'&& day='$day1'";
            
            $run = mysqli_query($link,$query1);            
            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td scope="col" style="border: 1px solid ;text-align: left;padding: 8px;color:black; background-color:grey;">
                      <button style="width:150px; height:50px; background-color:lightblue; color:black;  font-weight:900px; font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" ondblclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';"><B> <?php echo $row['class']; ?> </B></button>                      
                    </td>
                    <td scope="col" style="border: 1px solid ;text-align: left;padding: 8px;color:black; background-color:pink;">
                      <h3 id="demo"> Class:
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="dropbtn">Class Option</button>
                          <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="myFunction(); selectOnlyThis(this.id); " value="box1" name="checkbox[]" Size="12"><label for="1">Held</label></input>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="myFunction1(); selectOnlyThis(this.id); " value="box2" name="checkbox[]" Size="12"><label for="2">Cancel</label></input>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </h3>
                      <?php echo $row['slot1']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td scope="col" style="border: 1px solid ;text-align: left;padding: 8px; color:black; background-color:grey;">
                      <button style="width:320px; height:50px; background-color:white; color:black; font-weight:900px; font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" ondblclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';"> <?php echo $row['slot2']; ?> </button>
                    </td>
                    <td scope="col" style="border: 1px solid ;text-align: left;padding: 8px;color:black; background-color:grey;">
                      <button style="width:320px; height:50px; background-color:white; color:black; font-weight:900px; font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS;  " onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" ondblclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';"> <?php echo $row['slot3']; ?> </button>
                    </td>
                    <td scope="col" style="border: 1px solid ;text-align: left;padding: 8px; color:black; background-color:grey;">
                      <button style="width:320px; height:50px; background-color:white; font-weight:900px; font-size:16px; color:black; font-family:Comic Sans MS; " onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" ondblclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';"> <?php echo $row['slot4']; ?> </button> 
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
            }
           ?>
              </table>
              <!-- end slider -->
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- APP NAME -->
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div class="footer container container-fluid">
      <!-- COPYRIGHT - EDIT HOWEVER YOU WANT! -->
      <div id="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2017 <a href="#">UIIT @ PMAS AAUR </a>. All Rights Reserved</div>
      <!-- CREDIT - PLEASE LEAVE THIS LINK! -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementById('1')` is a bad idea. Id must represent the purpose of the element + prefix for element type. So it can be something like `chkSelectRow1`

Comment: `Id must represent the purpose of the element` - must is a bit strong, perhaps "should" would be a better word to use `+ prefix for element type` - again, that's your *opinion* or your *coding style*, it's not a requirement for html/javascript/css

Comment: can you populate the code with generated content. Add some more html elements as example (which will be generated from the db)

Comment: Did not get your question Sagar ?

Comment: Did you got the question now? did you aware of `radio`

Comment: yes radio button

Comment: Then try to use it. It will automatically unselect others while selecting one

Comment: i am using checkbox because i want to count no of class at the end which were held

Comment: Second i want to change label color when i choose any option how i can do it with radio button ?

Comment: you can add an eventlistener to all radio buttons to change color

Comment: can i add a database file to this question ? it may help in explaining this question better

Answer (score 0):

In Below function

```
 function selectOnlyThis(id) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i).checked = false;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

when you are doing getElementById, it will always get you the first element on the DOM matching the given id.
Hence it wont work for 2nd and above row.

You can be more generic and pass only "this" instead of "this.id"

```
function selectOnlyThis(elem) {
        var parentDiv = elem.parentElement.parentElement; 
        var buttons = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i =0; i< buttons.length; i++){
          if(buttons[i] !== elem)
          buttons[i].checked = false;
        }
        elem.checked = true;
      }
```

here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/v8zbpynz/

Comment: how passing `this` will make a difference while unchecking others

Comment: with `this` you can refer to parent element and than to that elemet you can find the elementsByTagName("button")

Comment: then i have to change  onclick event also ? the funation name ?

Comment: i tried use radio button with the function and this instead of this.id, but result is same the function did not work on other rows it only change color of first row even i am checking the any other row

Comment: updated the answer for check box changes, same way you can do it for color change

Mark it as answer if you find it useful